# Why doesn't the upload link generated by the Google Cloud Storage invalidate itself after a successful upload?

Tags: java, upload, google-cloud-storage

I have a `JAVA` method that gets me an `URL`, using which I can upload an object to the bucket in Google Cloud Storage. The generated `URL` is valid for 30 seconds(tested ok).

```
public String getSignedUploadLink(String bucketName, String objectName, String mimeType)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        // check if bucket exists, and create one with notification, if it doesn't.
        if (!bucketExists(bucketName)) {
            createBucket(bucketName);
        }

        // Define Resource
        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName)).build();

        // Specify the object's content type.
        Map<String, String> extensionHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        extensionHeaders.put("Content-Type", mimeType);

        //setting it to expire in 30 seconds
        return storage.signUrl(
                blobInfo,
                30,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                Storage.SignUrlOption.httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT),
                Storage.SignUrlOption.withExtHeaders(extensionHeaders),
                Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature()).toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle the caught exception
    }
}
```

Using `HTTP PUT` in the link generated by the above method, I can successfully upload an object in the Google Cloud Storage. The weird thing is, I'm also able to upload another object (with the same content type, of course) if I send another `PUT` request to the same `URL` before the expiration period.

Is it supposed to work like this? I was under the impression that, once an upload link is used to upload something, it invalidates itself, regardless of the expiration period. Could it be so that I'm missing something here? Could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the way it works.  There is nothing in the [documentation for signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that suggests that they invalidate themselves by any condition other than the time you specify when you create it.  If you say it's good for 30 seconds, then that's how long the URL can be used.